# mezzanine shop is not shown if behind a virtualhost

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualhost, mezzanine

I developed my first shop using mezzanine.

If I run it with `python manage runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` it works well, but if I try to put an apache virtualhost in front of it, the result I get is awful, because I only see the home page, but not the other ones.

I checked the generated HTML, and it looks very different.

I think it's a problem of mezzanine configuration, maybe on the configured sites, but I am not able to understand what I have to change.

Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: Where's your code? Let's see your **views.py** and **urls.py** at the very least. Also, your Apache config.

Comment: I did not change views or urls, it's a pure mezzanine site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've misconfigured the "sites" section.

Under "sites" in the admin interface, you'll find each configured site. Each of the pages in a site is related to one of these, and matched to the host name you use in the browser.

You'll probably find there's only one site record configured, and its domain doesn't match your production host that you're accessing the site via. If you update it, it should resolve everything.